# Why do I get an error when i use .json()?

Tags: python, json, error-handling, python-requests

I got an error when i use .json(), I followed a tutorial when i wrote this, I'm pretty sure I didn't changed anything but it doesn't work

Code:

```
import requests
import os #not used
import json #not used
import shutil #not used

header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36"}

url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CRlNMq5KawJ/"
tail = "?__a=1"
full_url = url + tail

response = requests.get(full_url, headers=header).json()

image_location = response["graphql"]["shortcode_media"]["display_resources"]
image_location = image_location[2].get("src")
print(image_location)
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\3001l\PycharmProjects\Instagram_Bot\Insta_Downloader.py", line 12, in <module>
    response = requests.get(full_url, headers=header).json()
  File "C:\Users\3001l\PycharmProjects\Instagram_Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\3001l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\3001l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\3001l\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you tried to see what th response is actually returning?

Comment: You are assuming there is a JSON value to decode in the response. That's not true if you get (for example) a 404 response instead of a 200 response.

Comment: Without the literal text of the response (_before_ conversion to JSON), this question isn't answerable -- we can make guesses, but that's not what we're here for.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with that URL. There may be a firewall blocking you, or Instagram is blocking you. If you send too many requests you may exceed a rate limit.

Comment: We can make guesses, by just trying ;) Instagram does not like anonymous calls to it and sets a rather strict limit on its access. If you print ```response.status_code``` i assume you get ```429``` which is Too Many Requests error

Comment: I am able to get the json response from the url. Your traceback error might indicate some error in your headers. May be try updating your browser

Comment: @Varsha did you try it in the browser or with python?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because the response is not json itself,or is not properly json-formatted.
try printing out requests.get(full_url, headers=header)

Comment: To general and wrong in this case, he is getting an request limit error..

Answer (score 0):

Some error with your headers, these are working, for me.

```
import requests

headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"}

response = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/CRlNMq5KawJ/?__a=1",headers=headers)

if response.status_code != 200:
    print("Some error happened, review response.text")
else:
    content = response.json()
```

Comment: Idk if i can but i tried your code and this doesn't work for me, the error is still on the .json() part, the last line in your case. Also tried with another pc

Comment: You get status_code == 200? and it still doesnt work?

Comment: Exactly, I tried both with your user agent and mine but the status code is always 200, I tried it on pycharm and in an online interpreter, same thing.

Comment: What is the content of ```response.text```

Comment: I cant copy all the text, check it out [here](https://wooden-shadow-b18.notion.site/Sorry-too-long-for-stackoverflow-7c243ddf56ad4f1984efccbbfc2a2b84)